# Does bean/pea milk made by just blending cooked beans/peas come out just as well as making it by blending soaked beans/peas and boiling them?

Tags: flavor, milk, beans

So I am vegan and make my own bean and pea milk using mostly Northern White beans and green split peas(finding the yellow ones is a bit hard). I have not made soymilk yet. Anyway, the way I make the bean/peamilk is by cooking them in a crockpot, then blending them in my *Nutribullet*. I also usually add bananas, sugar, and/or fat(cooking oil/*Crisco*).

But from what I heard and seen, most people make Bean/peamilk by soaking them overnight, and then blending them and boiling it and filtering it.

Does just cooking and blending get the same result as if I 'properly' made the milk?